# Copying conditional formatting with VLOOKUP across columns

Tags: excel, vlookup, conditional-formatting

I am formatting cell D25 using the following conditional formatting formula:

```
=(VLOOKUP($C25;$C$6:$L$18;2)+D25)>32
```

When applying the formula to the adjacent column I get formula updates to

```
 =(VLOOKUP($C25;$C$6:$L$18;**2**)+E25)>32
```

Using the Copy and Paste Format function works mostly i.e. references in the formula are updated as I would expect.

The only (essential) thing that doesn't update is the INDEX value in the VLOOKUP formula. I would expect this value to increase by 1 when copying the format to the next column - it doesn't.

Is there any way to go around this issue with VLOOKUP? Is there a better suited formula to achieve the same result?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Not sure I get your point. I am wondering whether there is a different function or formula that could help achieve what VLOOKUP does.

Answer (score 0):

This value does not increase automatically, and it is good. This formula was designed to be used on Tables, so consistency is a point here.

For conditional formatting, you may want to use $ to lock some references. For example, let we have the simple sheet as below:

[image]

First, select the range in the CORRECT order. This is important. the first cell you select will be reference for offsets of the conditional formatting. For this example, let's do it like this:

[image]

Now, let's go for the conditional formatting itself! Conditional Formatting > New Rule... > Use a formula to determine which cells to format. And let's put this formula:

=if($A1<=2;TRUE;FALSE)

Click OK and...

[image]

There we go! We just formatted the lines in witch An is equal or less than 2! Please note that we only had to lock the COLUMN of the reference. So, logically, to format the columns we would have locked the ROW.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT:**

If you REALLY want to use VLOOKUP, which I DO NOT recommend, you can just use the formula:

=(VLOOKUP($C25;$C$6:D$18;COLUMNS($C$6:D$18))+E25)>32

To change the index dinamically.